# How save a part of a map with Mapsui?

Tags: c#, mapsui

For a project, i'd like to save a part of a map and use it when i'm offline.

I'd like to know if it is possible to save a part of map using Mapsui ?

I already search but I didn't found something good..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is just the image of the map you could look at the test file 'MapRendererTests.cs'. It shows how you can save a map extent as an image.

```cs
var bitmap = new MapRenderer().RenderToBitmapStream(viewport, map.Layers, map.BackColor);
```

There is no support for saving the geometries themselves.

Comment: Is there a way to save polygons drawn over the map. I used the Polygons contained in Mapsui.UI.Forms namespace.

Comment: @BryanNoronha You are trying to save the map view as image and the forms' polygons are missing?

Comment: I believe Mapsui doesn't save the polygons drawn on top of the map. I was reading the docs and I came across a comment that said Mapsui doesnt support saving polygons and other shapes drawn on top of the map.

Comment: The shapes drawn on top of the map with XF elements are not but it is also possible to draw points lines and polygons with 'native' Mapsui geometries.